# How to create html table having 8 colums looking as form so the user can enter data from view?

Tags: html, css

Screent shot is Available in following given screen shot.
I infact want to create the bill in html so user can create bill from view.
How this is possible?
[image: I have created the table but i cannot enter value from view]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where did you get stuck - with that, it will be much easier for the people to give you concrete advice.

Comment: Yes it's possible. It looks like it could be bootstrap

Comment: i have created this table but from view it is not possible for me to enter values in table

Answer (score 1):

This is very easily doable through bootstrap. Based on the screenshot you provided, you can create the initial 'container' div element within the body. Afterwards you can then create two rows, one for the 'date' 'to' and 'bill no'. This row can have a col-md-3 for the 'date', a col-md-6 for the 'to' and a col-md-3' for the 'bill no'. This will make it responsive and will keep you from ideally having to manually do much padding to get things aligned.

For the table, you can simply add a table element and add a bootstrap class of table, which is 'class="table"'.

Here is a link to the bootstrap grid system for guidance on how to do your rows/columns: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Here is the link for doing your bootstrap dropdown for the 'to' and the tables: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: i have created the table but problem is this that i cannot enter value in cell of table.

Comment: you can always add inputs to table row or table data and then remove the borders from the inputs themselves through css. Ill try to update when I have some time to create a fiddle for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a textbox inside the cell(column)-
here is the code-

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It will insert a textbox inside the cell.